# What is the difference bewteen nginx against mp4 modules

Tags: nginx

What is the difference between the mp4 module  and the slice module for streaming mp4 videos in nginx? Both seem to work on streaming mp4 files but I can't really see the difference.

On another aspect, the slice module seems to work nicely with the caching. Where slices from cache module are stored and served to the users. Can the same be done to the mp4 module i.e., to have responses from the mp4 module cached ?

```
location / {
slice             1m;
proxy_cache       cache;
proxy_cache_key   $uri$is_args$args$slice_range;
proxy_set_header  Range $slice_range;
proxy_cache_valid 200 206 1h;
proxy_pass        http://localhost:8000;
```

}